# When I use tsconfig in Visual Studio I get compiler errors but when I removed it I dont

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript-typings, tsconfig

Hello this in regards this project not picking up the typescript definition files when I am use custom tsconfig instead of the one that Visual Studio automatically set up for me.

https://github.com/jvelezc/GridStackDemo/tree/master/src/GridStackDemo

The question is how is the tsconfig changing the discover ability of the typings definition?

I have a very simple tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave":true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "system",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "files": [
    "/wwwroot/app/**/*.ts",
    "/typings/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

If I use it (instead of the default Visual studio built in capability for configuring typescript options) then my typings definitions are not being read and I get angular is not defined.

When I use it notice it says cannot find name angular
[image]

When I don't use it
[image]

If I drag the typings definition 
/// 
Then it works. The question is how is the tsconfig changing the discover ability of the typings definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use glob pattern in `tsconfig.json` - your `files` section is not valid. If you want to use it you should specify files one by one. Also `exclude` can't be used together with `files` (`files` will win in case both specified).

The solution for your problem - just **remove** `files` section. See [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) for more information.